# session.delete() is not working in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am trying to perform a delete operation using session.delete() but it is not working, and it looks like Sometimes Hibernate silently decides not to delete an entity.

this is my code

```
@ApiOperation("")
    @Permit(action = "merge", resource = "Person")
    @Path("/person")
    @POST
    public List<String> mergePeople(@Context Session session, @BeanParam RequestPayload req) throws APIException {
        Person keepPerson;
        Person deletePerson;
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean commit = req.getQueryAsBoolean("commit");
        boolean sendNotification = false;

        try {
            if (req.getQuery().containsKey("keepPerson")) {
                Long idNew = getFirstQueryFromRequestAsLong(req, "keepPerson");
                Long idOld = getFirstQueryFromRequestAsLong(req, "deletePerson");
                keepPerson = getPerson(session, idNew);
                deletePerson = getPerson(session, idOld);
            } else if (req.getQuery().containsKey("person1")) {
                Long id1 = getFirstQueryFromRequestAsLong(req, "person1");
                Long id2 = getFirstQueryFromRequestAsLong(req, "person2");
                Person person1 = getPerson(session, id1);
                Person person2 = getPerson(session, id2);
                keepPerson = getNewerPerson(person1, person2);
                deletePerson = keepPerson == person1 ? person2 : person1;
            } else {
                String errorMsg = "Must specify people to be merged with keys 'person1' and 'person2', or 'keepPerson' and 'deletePerson'.";
                log.error(errorMsg);
                throw APIException.createBadRequestAPIException(errorMsg, null, 92183749L);
            }

            if (keepPerson.getId().equals(deletePerson.getId())) {
                log.error("Both people have same id");
                throw APIException.createBadRequestAPIException("Both people have same id", null, 298374928L);
            }

            messages.add(getTimestampMessage(deletePerson));
            messages.add(getTimestampMessage(keepPerson));
            messages.add("The person to keep is " + keepPerson.getId());

            sendNotification = shouldSendNotification(deletePerson, keepPerson);

            List<String> mergeMessages = mergePeopleAndDeleteOld(session, keepPerson, deletePerson);
            messages.addAll(mergeMessages);
        } catch (APIException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.setData(messages);
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

        if (commit) {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            // Sometimes Hibernate silently decides not to delete an entity
            checkIfDeleted(session, deletePerson);
            messages.add("Changes/deletions saved");
            log.info("Changes/deletions saved");
            
            // Free up orphaned email address from Chaser account for later use
            chaserClient.invalidateAccountEmail(deletePerson.getId());
            messages.add("Old Chaser email invalidated");

            if (sendNotification) {
                veslClient.enqueueJob(PersonMergeNotificationJob.QUEUE_NAME,
                        new PersonMergeNotificationJob(deletePerson.getId(), keepPerson.getId()), RequestUtil.getHeaders());
            }
        } else {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            messages.add("Changes/deletions rolled back");
            
        }
        session.close();
        return messages;
    }
```

the delete operation is happening her

```
public List<String> mergePeopleAndDeleteOld(Session session, Person keepPerson, Person deletePerson) throws APIException {
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

        // Delete member notes from person
        if (deletePerson.getMemberNotes() != null && !deletePerson.getMemberNotes().isEmpty()) {
            // deletes notes from person locally
            deletePerson.setMemberNotes(new ArrayList<>());
            // syncs delete with DB
            session.flush();
        }

        // Check that we can discard old person
        checkIfNonDeletable(session, keepPerson, deletePerson);

        mergeSponsorships(session, keepPerson, deletePerson);
        messages.add("Delete person sponsorships: " + deletePerson.getAllRelevantSponsorships());

        mergePlanMemberships(session, keepPerson, deletePerson);
        messages.add("Delete person plan memberships: " + deletePerson.getAllRelevantPlanMemberships());

        // update all dependent claim with keepPerson subscriber
        List<String> dependentClaimsMessages = mergeDependentClaims(session, keepPerson, deletePerson);
        messages.add("Delete person dependent claim: " + dependentClaimsMessages);

        mergeSpendingAccounts(session, keepPerson, deletePerson);
        messages.add("Delete person spending accounts: " + deletePerson.getSpendingAccounts());

        // If we made it here, it is safe to delete! :-O
        List<String> copyMessages = copyData(session, keepPerson, deletePerson);
        messages.addAll(copyMessages);

        messages.add("Deleting person: " + deletePerson);
        session.delete(deletePerson);
        session.flush();
        log.info("Deleting person: " + deletePerson.getId());

        messages.add("Saving person: " + keepPerson);
        session.save(keepPerson);
        log.info("Saving person: " + keepPerson.getId());

        return messages;
    }
```

this is the person class I am trying to delete

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({PersonEntityListener.class, BaseModelEntityListener.class})
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue("person")
@AddressConstraint
@Audited
@FilterDefs({
        @FilterDef(name = "validPlanMembershipFilter"),
        @FilterDef(name = "planMembershipStartDateRangeFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "startDate", type = "date")),
        @FilterDef(name = "planMembershipEndDateRangeFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "endDate", type = "date")),
        @FilterDef(name = "sponsorFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "sponsorId", type = "long")),
        @FilterDef(name = SpendingAccount.VALID_SPENDING_ACCOUNT_FILTER)
})
public class Person extends BaseUser implements PartnerChangeRelevance {

 
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Person.class);

    // TODO: extend validation for various formats... country codes?
    // international? extensions?
    @Column(name = "primary_phone", length = 12)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{3}-?\\d{3}-?\\d{4}$")
    @Expose(serialize = false)
    private String primaryPhone;

    @Column(name = "primary_phone_type")
    @MatchStrings(values = { PhoneNumberType.PHONE_TYPE_HOME, PhoneNumberType.PHONE_TYPE_CELL, PhoneNumberType.PHONE_TYPE_WORK,
            PhoneNumberType.PHONE_TYPE_UNKNOWN })
    @Expose(serialize = false)
    private String primaryPhoneType;

    // Shortcut to mark the relationship type between a subscriber
    // and dependent, rather than going through Sponsorship
    @Expose
    @Transient
    private String relationshipType;

    public String getRelationshipType() {
        return relationshipType;
    }

    public void setRelationshipType(String relationshipType) {
        this.relationshipType = relationshipType;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    @Expose
    @NotEmpty
    @Sortable
    @OverridableField
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    @Expose
    @Sortable
    @OverridableField
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    @Expose
    @NotEmpty
    @Sortable
    @OverridableField
    private String lastName;

    // This field is here for search purpose. It is probably going to be
    // removed.
    // Do not depend on it - instead expose the getter if you need it.
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    // i.e. Jr., Sr., III, etc
    @Column(name = "name_suffix")
    @Expose
    @Sortable
    @OverridableField
    private String nameSuffix;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DELETE })
    @Expose
    // TODO: validate that these are real addresses
    private Set<PersonAddress> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * yyyy-mm-dd
     */
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    @Expose
    @NotNull
    @Sortable
    @OverridableField
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    /**
     * ssn stored as string of 9 digits
     */
    @Transient
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{9}$", message = "An SSN must be nine numeric characters.")
    @Expose
    @RestrictToRoles({ Role.MACHINE_USER, Role.CH_ADMIN })
    @ExposeOnlyIfRequested
    @Sortable
    @OverridableField
    private String ssn;

    /**
     * encrypted ssn
     */
    @Column(name = "encrypted_ssn")
    @Expose
    @RestrictToRoles({ Role.MACHINE_USER, Role.CH_ADMIN })
    @ExposeOnlyIfRequested
    @OverridableField
    private String encryptedSsn;

    /**
     * ssn stored as string of 9 digits
     */
    @Column(name = "ssn_last_four", length = 4)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{4}$", message = "Last four of SSN must be four numeric characters.")
    @Expose
    @RestrictToRoles({ Role.MACHINE_USER, Role.CH_ADMIN })
    @ExposeOnlyIfRequested
    @Sortable
    private String ssnLastFour;

    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
    @MatchStrings(values = { GENDER_MALE, GENDER_FEMALE, GENDER_OTHER })
    @Expose
    @NotEmpty
    @Sortable
    @OverridableField
    private String gender;

    // TODO: delete when we stop getting this on the person field
    @Column(name = "salary")
    @Deprecated
    @Expose
    @ExposeOnlyIfRequested
    private BigDecimal salary;

    /**
     * Whether a welcome email has been sent in current open enrollment
     */
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "oe_email_sent", nullable = false)
    private boolean isOEEmailSent;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE })
    @Expose
    @Filters({
            @Filter(name = "planSubGroupFilter", condition = "plan_sub_group_id in (:planSubGroupIds)"),
            @Filter(name = "validPlanMembershipFilter", condition = "is_valid='true'"),
            @Filter(name = "planMembershipStartDateRangeFilter", condition = "not (end_date is not null and end_date < :startDate)"),
            @Filter(name = "planMembershipEndDateRangeFilter", condition = "start_date <= :endDate")
    })
    private Set<PlanMembership> planMemberships = new HashSet<>();

    @Transient
    // the set of plan memberships that are being imported right now
    private Set<PlanMembership> importedPlanMemberships = new HashSet<>();

    @Expose
    @Transient
    @Deprecated
    private Boolean isPHIAuthorized;

    @Expose
    @Transient
    private PhiAuthLevelName phiLevel;

    @Expose
    @Transient
    @Deprecated
    // The PHI authorization info needed in the family unit API response, from
    // the perspective of the grantor
    private PHIAuthorization phiAuthorization;

    @Expose
    @Transient
    private Boolean isFinancialAuthorized;

    @Expose
    @Transient
    private FinancialAuthorization financialAuthorization;

    /**
     * An id sent in the request for referring to the data in this particular
     * element of the request.
     */
    @Expose
    @Transient
    private String requestReferenceId;

    /**
     * All PlanMemberships where this person is the subscriber.
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "subscriber")
    @Filters({
            @Filter(name = "validPlanMembershipFilter", condition = "is_valid='true'"),
            @Filter(name = "planMembershipStartDateRangeFilter", condition = "not (end_date is not null and end_date < :startDate)"),
            @Filter(name = "planMembershipEndDateRangeFilter", condition = "start_date <= :endDate")
    })
    private Set<PlanMembership> familyPlanMemberships = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * All DependentSponsorships where this person is the subscriber. This field
     * is used to get a person's relationships to their dependents.
     */

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "subscriber")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE })
    @Expose
    @Filter(name = "sponsorFilter", condition = "sponsor_id=:sponsorId")
    private Set<DependentSponsorship> relationshipsToDependents = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * All sponsorships where this person is the person covered. Includes
     * SubscriberSponsorships and DependentSponsorships.
     */

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE })
    @Expose
    @NotEmpty
    @Filter(name = "sponsorFilter", condition = "sponsor_id=:sponsorId")
    private Set<Sponsorship> sponsorships = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE })
    @Expose
    @NotAudited
    @Filter(name = SpendingAccount.VALID_SPENDING_ACCOUNT_FILTER, condition = "status != 'INVALID'")
    private Set<SpendingAccount> spendingAccounts = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    @Expose
    // Cascade not needed as we are not modifying/persisting the cob on update
    // of person
    private Set<COB> cobs = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_member_note", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "member_note_id"))
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    private List<MemberNote> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * The memberIds this person has as the primary subscriber with various
     * partners.
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "subscriber")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @NotAudited
    private List<PartnerMemberId> partnerMemberIds = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "tos_agreement_date")
    @Expose
    // TODO: figure out the legal requirements around updating this field
    private LocalDate tosAgreementDate;

    // Id of matching auditcore obj, returned to help auditcore match objects
    @Transient
    @Expose
    private Long auditId;
```

any idea why delete is not working?

tried to add session.flush() after the delete then session.close() with no luck

Answer (score 0):

try sesion.remove(yourObj); ...